# ineffective computed loop in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've got array as below:

```
return {
   items: [
      { active: false, text: 'text1', textOutput: ''},
      { active: false, text: 'text1', textOutput: ''},
      { active: false, text: 'text1', textOutput: ''},
      ...
   ],
}
```

now, the purpose of this array is to output data to the DOM, using computed property as below.

I want to output only the data where active: true, which is changing onclick in other part of the web, so computed resultDOM is watching for this change and changing only `items.active="true"`. Also I use text-fields to change `items.text[i]` values.

```
computed: {
 resultDOM () {
        for (var i=0; i<this.items.length; i++) {
          if (this.items[i].active) {
            this.items[i].textOutput = '<li>' + this.items[i].text + '</li>'
            console.log('bam')
          }
          else {
            this.items[i].textOutput = ''
            console.log('bam else')
          }          
        }
        var output=''
        for (var i=0; i<this.items.length; i++) {
          output = output + this.items[i].textOutput
        }
        return output
 }
}
```

The problem is that this takes some time to execute and every time I change only one active to true (or items.text value) computed is doing check on every element of the table, so it's very ineffective. 
Can I ask you for tips, how should I improve my code to be more efficient? 
What is the right way to do it?

edit:

```
<div  v-html="resultDOM"></div>
```

Comment: can you provide a template for the component? I guess you could use conditional rendering.

Comment: @oniondomes I added to question. I could use it, but I also need textOutput values for future use (save it to database/other components)

Comment: I saw you comment too late. I will revise my answer.

Comment: @oniondomes that's ok, your answer seems correct, the main idea to stick to computed is that I will use it in the future to dynamically change elements of page like <li> objects inside computed and to get the reusable finished HTML this way in many variants

Comment: It's hard to answer without a context. If you really want to keep html inside your `computed` (which isn't a good idea imo), this is your way to go I guess.

Comment: @oniondomes thank you for your answer, but it seems I need to use computed. The main problem is to make it more effective

Comment: you can at least not iterate through the array twice. put `output = output + this.items[i].textOutput` inside the first loop.

Comment: @oniondomes that's a good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using `computed` at all if you take advantage of conditional rendering and `v-for` directive:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      { active: true, text: 'text1',},
      { active: true, text: 'text2',},
      { active: false, text: 'text3',},
    ],
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" v-if="item.active" v-text="item.text"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/yksLh5g3/)

Comment: Good, don't forget the `:key` attribute when you are using `v-for` ;) https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: @thomas-brodusch, one should indeed use `v-key` when it's possible, but the sample data doesn't really provide any unique values to be keys.

Comment: You are right, but you can totally formate a key like this: `:key="'itemKey_${index}'"`  with `index` from `v-for="item, index in item` to make a custom unique key if no unique value is provided.

Comment: @thomas-brodusch I thought about this, but won't `index` get changed every time you delete anything from the array? It kinda defeats the purpose of `:key`.

Comment: Of course if the `items` array get changed, the index will also by updated.  Using `:key="'itemKey_${index}'"` is a tweak to prevent any VueJS's error to be thrown about a missing `:key` parameter if you haven't pass it one. It also provide you to unique-ify each item when you have to render out multiple list-based components in the same context. There is a great topic about it here https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-for-with-simple-arrays-what-key-to-use/13692/5

Comment: @thomas-brodusch agree to everything said, but there are still no child components involved. Even a participant of the thread you shared is saying there's no need for `key` attribute in such case (here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-for-with-simple-arrays-what-key-to-use/13692/3). I am not saying you're wrong in general, what I want to say is that in this particular case you can't take advantage of `key`. If I was in such situation I would rather restructure my data to fit the requirements, rather than using these tricks with array indexes. Anyways, this is beyond the question scope.

Comment: I totally agree with you.